# How to URL rewrite using htaccess without folder name interference?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not really sure about the title but how would i be able to do this with .htaccess

> test.com/marketplace/index.php?type=1

to this

> test.com/marketplace/1

where marketplace is an actual folder on the server.
ive tried

`RewriteRule ^marketplace/([^/]*)$ /marketplace/index.php?type=$1 [L]`

But no luck. what do? :(

Comment: have you activated the RewriteEngine?

Comment: yes RewriteEngine on

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: error message? where do i look for that?

Comment: try adding in the [QSA] flags

Comment: Is there a 500 error when you open a web page or is the browser saying infinite redirect / took too long or is the rewrite just not accessible?

Comment: @MEE yes 500 error Juakali92  tried that no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the destination you are rewriting to .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/marketplace/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^marketplace/([^/]*)$ /marketplace/index.php?type=$1 [L]
```

Otherwise you get an `infinite loop` error  because the pattern `^marketplace/([^/]*)$` also matches the destination path `/marketplace/index.php?type=$1` .